# beeline reserved character while running database scripts

Tags: oracle, hive, beeline

I just encountered a problem when running hive/oracle scripts through beeline. 
Error:

> Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ 0:
>   jdbc:hive2://ro41hdp02a.infra.bird.bi.eb-g> 0:
>   jdbc:hive2://ro41hdp02a.infra.bird.bi.eb-g> 0:
>   jdbc:hive2://ro41hdp02a.infra.bird.bi.eb-g> alter table
>   digital_onboarding_fat01.do_applsbpm add
>   columns(doa_accessed_cross_sell    VARCHAR(5) COMMENT 'The column
>   indicates if the client has accessed the cross sell win dow. Can take
>   the following values True the client has accessed the Insurance card,
>   available on the Cross Sell window. False the client has chosen Nu
>   sunt inte resat in the Cross Sell window. Blank  the client didnt
>   reach the Cross sell step.', doa_acquired_insurance VARCHAR(5) COMMENT
>   'The column indicates if the client has purchased an insurance. Ca n
>   take the following values True the client choses an insurance, doesnt
>   uncheckit in the Basket summary step and goes further to Contract;
>   False the client cho ses an insurance, but unchecks it in the Basket
>   summary step; Blank the client doesnt chose any insurance / he didnt
>   reach the Basket summary step.'); Error: Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:48 mismatched input 'The'
>   expecting StringLiteral near 'COMMENT' in column specification
>   (state=42000,code=40000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you add comments (for my case), if you have semicolon (;) in your comment, it's considered a reserved character. So you should escape or delete it.